# Hamburger menu with Prism & xamarin forms doet not appear

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm trying to create a hamburger menu but when I launch the app I get an empty page. I'm using Prism to develop this android app and I followed this article: https://dansiegel.net/post/2017/04/01/the-hamburger-menu-with-prism-forms but for me it doesn't work.

MainPage.cs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<MasterDetailPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="HomeManagement.Views.MainPage">
    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
        <!-- Hamburger Menu Secret Sauce... Add an Icon!!!! Make sure it's in your resources for your Platform Project -->
        <NavigationPage Title="Required Foo" Icon="ic_launcher.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <ContentPage Title="Menu">
                    <StackLayout Padding="40">
                        <Label Text="Test hello" />
                        <Button Text="HuePage"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ContentPage>
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Master>
</MasterDetailPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HomeManagement.Views
{
    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

MainPageViewModel

```
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using Prism.Navigation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace HomeManagement.ViewModels
{
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Main hamburger";

        }
    }
}
```

Anyone a clue what is going on? I'm using Prism version 7.2.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you are assigning a MasterPage but you do not seem to be assigning a detail page which is, in turn, leaving your screen empty! Try assigning a detail page to it

```
MainPage mainPage = new MainPage();
mainPage.Detail= new DetailPage();
```

Or From XAML

```
 <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
       <ContentPage Title="Detail">
                <StackLayout Padding="40">
                    <Label Text="Test hello" />
                    <Button Text="HuePage"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ContentPage>
 </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

Comment: Hi, Yeah I saw when I added in xaml a Detail that it works. Thanks your time! Much appreciated.

Comment: If it works for you make sure you mark it as the answer for the others who have a similar issue, Also always happy to help :)